# iOS - How to achieve emboss effect for the text on UILabel?

Tags: iphone, uilabel, shadow, emboss

[image]

Can I know how to have the emboss effect as the text "**Reminders**" as shown on the picture?

It looks like the text are embedded?

Thanks

Answer (score 90, accepted):

### UPDATE FOR iOS 7.0

In iOS 7.0, Apple added a new attribute, `NSTextEffectAttributeName`, for attributed strings.  If your deployment target is iOS 7.0 or later, you can set this attribute to `NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle` to draw an attributed string in an embossed style.

### ORIGINAL

I can't say for certain how Apple draws the embossed text.  It looks to me like they fill the string glyphs with a reddish color, then apply a shadow around the interior edges of the glyphs, and also apply a very faint shadow along the top outside edges of the glyphs.  I tried it out and here's what it looks like:

[image: iPhone simulator screen shot]

On top is my rendering.  Below that is a simple UILabel with shadow as Chris suggested in his answer.  I put a screen shot of the Reminders app in the background.

Here's my code.

First, you need a function that creates an image mask of your string.  You'll use the mask to draw the string itself, and then to draw a shadow that only appears around the inside edges of the string.  This image just has an alpha channel and no RGB channels.

```
- (UIImage *)maskWithString:(NSString *)string font:(UIFont *)font size:(CGSize)size
{
    CGRect rect = { CGPointZero, size };
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGColorSpaceRef grayscale = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef gc = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width * scale, size.height * scale, 8, size.width * scale, grayscale, kCGImageAlphaOnly);
    CGContextScaleCTM(gc, scale, scale);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(grayscale);
    UIGraphicsPushContext(gc); {
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
        [string drawInRect:rect withFont:font];
    } UIGraphicsPopContext();

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(gc);
    CGContextRelease(gc);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);

    return image;
}
```

Second, you need a function that inverts that mask.  You'll use this to make CoreGraphics draw a shadow around the inside edges of the string.  This needs to be a full RGBA image.  (iOS doesn't seem to support grayscale+alpha images.)

```
- (UIImage *)invertedMaskWithMask:(UIImage *)mask
{
    CGRect rect = { CGPointZero, mask.size };
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, mask.scale); {
        [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
        UIRectFill(rect);
        CGContextClipToMask(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect, mask.CGImage);
        CGContextClearRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
    }
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

You can use those in a function that draws the string in red and applies a shadow to its interior edges.

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithInteriorShadowAndString:(NSString *)string font:(UIFont *)font textColor:(UIColor *)textColor size:(CGSize)size
{
    CGRect rect = { CGPointZero, size };
    UIImage *mask = [self maskWithString:string font:font size:rect.size];
    UIImage *invertedMask = [self invertedMaskWithMask:mask];
    UIImage *image;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale); {
        CGContextRef gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        // Clip to the mask that only allows drawing inside the string's image.
        CGContextClipToMask(gc, rect, mask.CGImage);
        // We apply the mask twice because we're going to draw through it twice.
        // Only applying it once would make the edges too sharp.
        CGContextClipToMask(gc, rect, mask.CGImage);
        mask = nil; // done with mask; let ARC free it

        // Draw the red text.
        [textColor setFill];
        CGContextFillRect(gc, rect);

        // Draw the interior shadow.
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(gc, CGSizeZero, 1.6, [UIColor colorWithWhite:.3 alpha:1].CGColor);
        [invertedMask drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        invertedMask = nil; // done with invertedMask; let ARC free it

        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Next you need a function that takes an image and returns a copy with a faint upward shadow.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithUpwardShadowAndImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale); {
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGSizeMake(0, -1), 1, [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.15].CGColor);
        [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    }
    UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultImage;
}
```

Finally, you can combine those functions to create an embossed image of your string.  I put my final image into a `UIImageView` for easy testing.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rect = self.imageView.bounds;
    NSString *string = @"Reminders";
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:33];
    UIImage *interiorShadowImage = [self imageWithInteriorShadowAndString:string
        font:font
        textColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:.9 brightness:.7 alpha:1]
        size:rect.size];
    UIImage *finalImage = [self imageWithUpwardShadowAndImage:interiorShadowImage];

    self.imageView.image = finalImage;
}
```

Comment: That's the best answer I've seen on SO so far. Well, with the exception of the one on how to parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: Can we get this as a gist as a category on UILabel please? :)

Comment: I think this is a great answer however the shadowing is a bit intense, it should be 1/5 of it is now in order to be an exact replica! :)

Comment: This code works spectacularly.  I needed it for a project, so I rolled the logic into a subclass of UILabel, which you can find here: https://gist.github.com/4019673

Comment: I like the way you structure the code using extra brackets to make context specifics clear to the reader.

Comment: I've tried this, but the text is in the top left corner. Is there something I can do easily draw the text so it is centred to the rect?  I want to create this text for a custom button. (EDIT) I think i would use the drawAtPoint to adjust.  I'll try that out.

Answer (score 4):

That just looks like a shadow around the text. You set it in IB in the same area where you set the text color - pick an appropriate color for the shadow and set how you want the shadow offset (in the example you posted, it looks like they set the shadow color to the same color as the text and offset it 0 horizontal and -1 vertical (which means one pixel up).

In code, the properties are set like this (assuming you have already set up a UILabel named, appropriately, "label":

```
label.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // Choose your color here - in the example
                                          // posted, they probably chose a similar color
                                          // to the text color and then set the alpha
                                          // down around 0.7 or so so the shadow would be
                                          // faint.
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,-1);    // First parameter is horizontal, second is vertical
```

Comment: This does not achieve the effect he is talking about.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure your effect on the basis of this example 
[image]

Comment: Useful answer as NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle has a processing overhead that can cause drawing delays. This (search for NSShadow for further details) is a lot quicker and in certain uses looks better.