# How to create several UIButtons along a path/BezierCurve?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

How can I create objects along a path/BezierCurve? In other words, how can I create several UIButtons along a given path, with a given interval along that same path?

I have seen dozens of questions about moving objects. But I need a solution to actually create them.

I would like to go along the path and create an object for every X points/distance. Like this:

```
....@....@....@....@....
```

In this case, for every 4 points, get the position, and create a UIButton there.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  You want to create objects along a path but not draw them on the screen?  Huh?

Comment: I'm trying to create multiple UIButton objects along a path. Is this possible? For every X points/distance I need to return the X/Y position, so I can create them.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to return the X/Y position with an animation along that path, but I'm not sure how I would tell te animation to trigger a given selector for each X points/distance, and return the position at the same time.

Comment: It's pretty easy to loop through and create UIButtons along a path using `setFrame` of the UIButton, but you are being pretty unclear about animations, etc.  The more clearly you can state your problem, the easier it will be for people to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to be as clear as possible. How would you create UIButtons along a given path, with a given interval? This is what I'm looking for. I will update the question to better reflect my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

iOS doesn't have a public API that directly gives you points spaced along a path.  But there is a roundabout way to do it.  Suppose you want points along the path spaced a distance of X apart.

First, create a `CGPathRef` containing your path.  (You can construct a `UIBezierPath` if you prefer and then gets its `CGPath` property.)

Then, call `CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath`, using a dash pattern of `{ X, X }`.  For example:

```
static CGFloat const kSpace = 10;
CGPathRef dashedPath = CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath(path, NULL, 0,
    (CGFloat const []){ kSpace, kSpace }, 2);
```

This returns a new path containing multiple subpaths. Each subpath is a length X segment of the original path, and is separated from its neighboring subpaths by a distance of X along the original path.  Thus the endpoints of the subpaths are spaced along the original path at an interval of length X.

So, finally, enumerate the dashed path using `CGPathApply`, picking the endpoints and creating buttons there.  First, you'll want to wrap it in a function that takes a block:

```
static void applyBlockToPathElement(void *info, const CGPathElement *element) {
    void (^block)(const CGPathElement *) = (__bridge void (^)(const CGPathElement *))(info);
    block(element);
}

void MyCGPathApplyBlock(CGPathRef path, void (^block)(const CGPathElement *element)) {
    CGPathApply(path, (__bridge void *)(block), applyBlockToPathElement);
}
```

Then you can apply a block that finds the each subpath endpoint and creates a button there.  Assuming you have a method named `createButtonAtPoint:`, something like this should work:

```
__block BOOL isInSubpath = NO;
__block CGPoint subpathStart = CGPointZero;
__block CGPoint currentPoint = CGPointZero;
MyCGPathApplyBlock(dashedPath, ^(const CGPathElement *element) {
    switch (element->type) {
        case kCGPathElementMoveToPoint:
            if (isInSubpath) {
                [self createButtonAtPoint:currentPoint];
                isInSubpath = NO;
            }
            currentPoint = element->points[0];
            break;

        case kCGPathElementCloseSubpath:
            // This should not appear in a dashed path.
            break;

        case kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint:
        case kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint:
        case kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint:
            if (!isInSubpath) {
                [self createButtonAtPoint:currentPoint];
                isInSubpath = YES;
            }
            int pointIndex =
                element->type == kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint ? 0
                : element->type == kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint ? 1
                : /* element->type == kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint ? */ 2;
            currentPoint = element->points[pointIndex];
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: You understood my problem perfectly. I'm still trying to wrap my head around it, but your solution looks very promising! Thank you for such a great answer kind Sir.

Comment: Just finished implementing this in my code. Good god, I'm amazed on how there wasn't a single typo in your code and how easily you came up with this. It works perfect! It's still a little ahead of my knowledge of the API, I don't think I would come even close to do this. Thank you again!

Comment: Thanks.  I wrote the code in Xcode to avoid errors and then copied it into the answer.  And I wouldn't say it was so easy. It's just that [I've used this technique before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13667092/77567).

Answer (score -1):

Have you solved your problem yet? if no, see this if it could help

```
  //if the interval is kown as float, suggesting it named padding

  //then you can

  for(i=0;i<numOfPaddings;i++){
      //create a button
      UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonRoundRect/*I forgot how to spell,but it does not metter*/];
      //Set your button's position base on padding
      [aButton setFrame:CGRectMake(padding+padding*i,20,50,20)];
  }
```

Comment: @rob mayoff gave a perfect answer to my problem, but thank you for helping out! Cheers =)