# Draggable UIButton Snap To a Circle Path

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am looking to make my UIButton be able to be draggable only around a circle I created through a draw rect.  I may need to make a circle path instead of the circle shape however I'm not quite sure about the approach to take as I am new to this.  Here is the code I have and I only want the button to be dragged around that circle or invisible path.  Any help or examples would be extremely helpful.  Thank You!

Edit: I used part of the answer below below but I am not sure how to get this to work correctly.  I want it to be the same size as my circle that I created so I am happy to create just a circle path and put it on top of the circle that I made.

```
//Button Code
timeSetButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [timeSetButton addTarget:self
                         action:nil
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [timeSetButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testButton.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        timeSetButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,415,50,50);
        [self.view addSubview:timeSetButton];

        //Button Listener
        [timeSetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];


//Draggable Button Code
// get the touch
UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:timeSetButton] anyObject];

// get delta
CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:timeSetButton];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:timeSetButton];
CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;

// move button
timeSetButton.center = CGPointMake(timeSetButton.center.x + delta_x,
                            timeSetButton.center.y + delta_y);

// enforce constraint on locations, by...

// working out the distance from the centre of the circle
CGPoint vectorFromCentreOfCircle =
CGPointMake(150,150);

CGFloat distanceFromCentreOfCircle = hypotf(vectorFromCentreOfCircle.x, vectorFromCentreOfCircle.y);

// working out what you'd need to multiply that distance by in order
// to get the specified radius
CGFloat correctionMultiplier = 20 / distanceFromCentreOfCircle;

// adjust vector from centre of circle
vectorFromCentreOfCircle.x *= correctionMultiplier;
vectorFromCentreOfCircle.y *= correctionMultiplier;

// move button one more time
timeSetButton.center = CGPointMake(
                    200 + vectorFromCentreOfCircle.x,
                    200 + vectorFromCentreOfCircle.y);
```

Here is the Circle Shape

```
circleView = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 100, 260, 260)];
        circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.view addSubview:circleView];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:circleView];
```

Comment: If you decide you want the button to follow a more complex path, [check out this q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13664615/77567).

Answer (score 2):

I actually needed the same and was watching your code. What you actually need to do is fetch the angle of the actual circle and then calculate the needed x and y on that. This is how I have done it:

```
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];

//Drawing the circle
CGPoint arcCenter = CGPointMake(385.0f, 700.0f);
CGFloat arcRadius = 140.0f;


// get delta
CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:button];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:button];
CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;


// move button
button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x, button.center.y + delta_y);

CGFloat angle = atan2((button.center.y - arcCenter.y), (button.center.x - arcCenter.x));

button.center = CGPointMake(arcCenter.x + arcRadius * cos(angle), arcCenter.y + arcRadius * sin(angle));
```

This gives me when I add a drag to a button the actual needed behavior. I used Touch Drag Outside and Inside to avoid the button to stop when you move your finger too much away from the button. I hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing it's probably sufficient just to add a quick bit of code after you've moved the button to enforce the constraint that it must be on the circle. E.g.

```
// move button
timeSetButton.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x,
                            button.center.y + delta_y);

// enforce constraint on locations, by...

// working out the distance from the centre of the circle
CGPoint vectorFromCentreOfCircle =
     CGPointMake(timeSetButton.center.x - centreOfCircle.x,
                 timeSetButton.center.x - centreOfCircle.y);

CGFloat distanceFromCentreOfCircle = 
     hypotf(vectorFromCentreOfCircle.x, vectorFromCentreOfCircle.y);

// working out what you'd need to multiply that distance by in order
// to get the specified radius
CGFloat correctionMultiplier = radiusOfCircle / distanceFromCentreOfCircle;

// adjust vector from centre of circle
vectorFromCentreOfCircle.x *= correctionMultiplier;
vectorFromCentreOfCircle.y *= correctionMultiplier;

// move button one more time
timeSetButton.center = CGPointMake(
          centreOfCircle.x + vectorFromCentreOfCircle.x,
          centreOfCircle.y + vectorFromCentreOfCircle.y);
```

Comment: `CGFloat distanceFromCentreOfCircle = hypotf(vectorFromCentreOfCircle.x, vectorFromCentreOfCircle.y);`

Comment: Thanks! on the centerOfCircle how am I calculating that? Do I need to figure that out and make a CGPoint value?

Comment: same with radiusOfCircle?

Comment: @GrantWilkinson it depends on how your `CircleView` works. If I had to guess, the centre of the circle is probably `circleView.center` and the circle radius is likely at least close to `(circleView.frame.size.width * 0.5f)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by knowing the distance of touchPoint from the center of the view

I'll make the following modification in your code. See if this works

```
- (void)wasDragged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // get the touch
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];

    // get delta
    CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:button];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:button];

    //calculate center of button in superView
    CGPoint buttonCenter = CGPointMake(button.frame.origin.x+(button.frame.size.width/2.0f),
                                       button.frame.origin.y+(button.frame.size.height/2.0f));
    //calculate the distance of current touchPoint from buttonCenter
    CGFloat diffx = location.x - buttonCenter.x;
    CGFloat diffy = location.y - buttonCenter.y;
    CGFloat distance = sqrtf((diffx*diffx)+(diffy*diffy));

    //check if the distance is within the radius of circle.
    //assuming that your button is always a square to make 
    //perfect circle within it.
    CGFloat radius = button.frame.size.width/2.0f;

    if(radius >= distance)//this makes a circular check.
    {
      CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
      CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;

      // move button
      timeSetButton.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x,
                                button.center.y + delta_y);
    }

}
```

Comment: where do I adjust the size of the circle radius?

Comment: in my code, the radius is determined by the half-width of the button's  frame. You can change it to any value.