# Glowing effect in a UILabel using inner shadow

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

I am trying to achieve this glowing effect for a **UILabel** as shown below :

### [image: Glow effect]

I have subclassed `UILabel` , and created a custom label class that adds an outer shadow.

**Edit :** Here's the code i have used for outer shadow/glow in my custom Label class :

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIColor *insideColor;
UIColor *blurColor;
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

insideColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:191/255.0 alpha:1];
blurColor =[UIColor orangeColor];    


    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, insideColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeMake(0, 0), self.glowAmount, blurColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextFillStroke);

    [self.text drawInRect:self.bounds withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode alignment:self.textAlignment];
}
```

But this gives me the following result

[image: MyImage]

As you can see this lacks the desired effect because of the missing **inner shadow.** Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - How to achieve emboss effect for the text on UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467141/ios-how-to-achieve-emboss-effect-for-the-text-on-uilabel) Rob Mayoff's answer here is fantastic - should get you the inner shadow you need.

Comment: This uses an UIImage. cant we do it to the UILabel text directly in - (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect method ?

Comment: Can you post all of the code relating to the label?

Comment: @Szwedo :  I have edited my question and posted the code m currently using.

Comment: Nayan, Can you post your updated code that works with ios7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred the answer by Steven XM for [Inner Shadow in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231690/inner-shadow-in-uilabel?answertab=active#tab-top) . It was a great help.

Here's what i have done to achieve the result but i want to know if this can be more optimized?

```
-(void)setInnerGlowWithColor:(UIColor *)shadowColor fillColor:(UIColor *)insideColor inRect:(CGRect)rect 
{

    UIFont *font = self.font;
   // UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17];
    CGSize fontSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:font];


    /****    Following are the steps to create an inside shadow ****/

    // STEP 1 :  Create a  image mask of your text.

        CGImageRef mask = [self createMaskWithSize:rect.size shape:^{
        [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
        CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
        // custom shape goes here
        [self.text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((self.bounds.size.width/2)-(fontSize.width/2), 0) withFont:font];
        }];


    // STEP 2 : Invert that mask.

        CGImageRef cutoutRef = CGImageCreateWithMask([self blackSquareOfSize:rect.size].CGImage, mask);
        CGImageRelease(mask);

        UIImage *cutout = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cutoutRef scale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        CGImageRelease(cutoutRef);  



     // STEP 3 : Use this inverted mask to draw a shadow around the inside edges of the text.

        CGImageRef shadedMask = [self createMaskWithSize:rect.size shape:^{
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
        CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
        //****************For inner shadow/glow
        NSLog(@"in custom label---->  %f",self.glowAmount);
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGSizeMake(0, 0), self.glowAmount, shadowColor.CGColor);
        [cutout drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        }];


    // STEP 4 : Create negative image

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
        [shadowColor setFill];
        // custom shape goes here
        [self.text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((self.bounds.size.width/2)-(fontSize.width/2), 0) withFont:font];
        UIImage *negative = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 


    // STEP 5 : Create the shadow image

        CGImageRef innerShadowRef = CGImageCreateWithMask(negative.CGImage, shadedMask);
        CGImageRelease(shadedMask);
        UIImage *innerShadow = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:innerShadowRef scale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        CGImageRelease(innerShadowRef);


    // STEP 6 : Draw actual text

        [insideColor setFill];
        [self.text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((self.bounds.size.width/2)-(fontSize.width/2), 0) withFont:font];  


    // STEP 7 : Finally apply the shadow image   

        [innerShadow drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

}


- (UIImage*)blackSquareOfSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);  
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    UIImage *blackSquare = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return blackSquare;
}


- (CGImageRef)createMaskWithSize:(CGSize)size shape:(void (^)(void))block {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);  
    block();
    CGImageRef shape = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() CGImage];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  
    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(shape),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(shape),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(shape),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(shape),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(shape),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(shape), NULL, false);
    return mask;
}
```